# Moving files older than one year to parent archive directory

Tags: find, rsync, mv

I want to move the photos of my collection into an "/home/Bruno/Archiv/Bilder" directory, which is parent to the "/home/Bruno/Bilder" Directory.

I started of with:

```
find  -ctime +365 -exec echo mv '{}' ../Archiv/Bilder/'{}' \; | bash
```

But find includes the dot for current directory in the {}. So I get:

```
mv ./2013/01/19/DSC_0141.JPG ../Archiv/Bilder/./2013/01/19/DSC_0141.JPG
mv: das Verschieben von »./2013/01/23/IMG_0052.JPG“ nach »../Archiv/Bilder/./2013/01/23/IMG_0052.JPG“ ist nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

So I stripped the dot of using sed:

```
find  -ctime +577 -exec echo mv '{}' ../Archiv/Bilder/'{}' \;  | sed 's/\/Bilder\/\.\//\/Bilder\//' | bash
```

But I get the same error:

```
mv: das Verschieben von »./2013/01/10/IMG_0141.JPG“ nach »../Archiv/Bilder/2013/01/10/IMG_0141.JPG“ ist nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

So I wanted to swich to rsync to do the job:

```
find  -ctime +577 -exec echo rsync -n --remove-source-files '{}' ../Archiv/Bilder/'{}' \;  | sed 's/\/Bilder\/\.\//\/Bilder\//' | bash
```

And rsync fails, but it is a lot more verbose about it:

```
rsync: change_dir#3 "/home/Bruno/Bilder//../Archiv/Bilder/2013/01/10" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(712) [Receiver=3.1.0]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your find command runs into the problem that the intermediate directories (in this case `/home/Bruno/Archiv/Bilder/2013/01/23/`) has not been created yet. That has nothing to do with the (harmless) '`.`' in your path.

You either have to first create the whole directory structure to the target or make a small script that you call instead of `mv` that first creates the target directory and then does the move.

`mkdirmv`:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p -- "$(dirname $2)"
mv -- "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am anyways working in a script. So I can just call them after one another by using find twice. "dirname" was new to me :-)

Comment: @Bruno Without looking at your script, that probably implies creating empty directories that might not (yet) get filled (that does not have to be a real problem). You might want to do a `find . -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} \;` it will complain about non-empty directories, but also remove any directories no longer filled.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference - you can use `install` to do this directly:

`install -D ./2013/01/10/IMG_0141.JPG ../Archiv/Bilder/2013/01/10/IMG_0141.JPG`

Note: you need to append the file path in the second argument for this to work. In other words:

**Incorrect**:

`find . -ctime +365 -exec install -D '{}' ../Archiv/Bilder/ \;`

**Correct**:

`find . -ctime +365 -exec install -D '{}' '../Archiv/Bilder/{}' \;`

According to man page of `install`:

> -D     create all leading components of DEST except the last, then copy SOURCE to DEST

Comment: I looked into the manpage of install. It does not seem to have an option to delete the source files. But the task was to move files into another directory.

Comment: Ah yes! Sorry I can't add comments yet - so had to post an answer. My answer was only for suggesting how to create complete directory on destination. You will have to add call `rm` explicitly using another `-exec` option to find.